# Can these connections be considered as permutations or combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, combinations

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use whatever words you want as long as you define them clearly.  I'm not sure why you'd want to use either "permutations" or "combinations", though.

Comment: @EricWofsey I was wondering if it’s mathematically correct to say either option in this context because I don’t want to keep saying “number of ways’ if there’s some terminology I can use instead of that. So I want to know which term can be correctly used here.

Comment: Please, do not try to call everything in combinatorics a combination or a permutation. These are very specific things; a permutation is a an ordered list of objects without repeats, and a combination is a subset of objects. What you are talking about is nothing like either of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you are counting is nothing like a permutation. A permutation refers to an ordered list of objects without repeats. Just because order matters, that does not make it a permutation.

The things you are counting are called [*matchings in the complete graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)). If you do not like that name, you can make up a new one, as long as you define this new term for your audience. I think a descriptive name would be a "pairing," or a "partial pairing."

In general, if you are counting some combinatoric object you made up and do not have a name for it, you can generally refer to the things you are counting as "arrangements," and say "the number of arrangements is...".

Comment: "Arrangements" works fine, thanks! Also, since I'm exploring involution numbers (which also refers to the number of permutations on $n$ elements), I was wondering if it would be right to use "permutations" here.. e.g. "2 possible permutations for A and B" or "4 possible permutations for A, B, and C". Or should I just refer to them as arrangements as you mentioned?

Comment: @Justin You could say that you are counting "involutions," e.g. "there are four involutions when $n=3$." I would not call what you are counting permutations, because that makes it seem like all permutations are allowed, when really only involutions are allowed.

Comment: Ohh okay, understood... Thank you!